# I need to pad IP addresses with Zeroes for each octet

Tags: bash, string

Starting with a string of an unspecified length, I need to make it exactly 43 characters long (front-padded with zeroes). It is going to contain IP addresses and port numbers. Something like:

```
### BEFORE
# Unfortunately includes ':' colon
66.35.205.123.80-137.30.123.78.52172:
### AFTER
# Colon removed.
# Digits padded to three (3) and five (5) 
# characters (for IP address and port numbers, respectively)
066.035.005.123.00080-137.030.123.078.52172
```

This is similar to the output produced by [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/).

Programming in Bash. I can provide copy of script if required.
If it's at all possible, it would be nice to use a bash built-in, for speed. Is `printf` suitable for this type of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses `IFS` to split the address info into an array. Then `printf` saves the formatted result back into the original variable for further processing. Pure Bash - no external executables are used.

```
addr='66.35.205.123.80-137.30.123.78.52172:'
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='.-:'
arr=($addr)
IFS=$saveIFS
printf -v addr "%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d.%05d-%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d.%05d" ${arr[@]}
do_something "$addr"
```

**Edit:**

Without using an array:

```
addr='66.35.205.123.80-137.30.123.78.52172:'
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='.-:'
printf -v addr "%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d.%05d-%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d.%05d" $addr
IFS=$saveIFS
do_something "$addr"
```

Comment: $IFS - you've helped me with that one more than once now DW :)

Comment: Accepted answer for using no outside executables.

Comment: This works. But I'd like to know why an array was used? Would a single variable with space-separated values _not_ do the job as well? Would it it conflict with `printf` in some way?

Comment: @Felipe: You can do it without the array. I'll post an edit that shows that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sounds like an excellent match for `printf`. You can probably use `cut` to split the incoming address into fields, which you can then feed back into `printf` to do the formatting.

Here's a quick sketch, it can certainly be improved to get the exact output format that you require:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function format_address()
{
    printf "%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d.%05d" $(echo $1 | cut -d'.' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1-5)
}

for a in $(echo $1 | tr -d ':' | cut -d '-' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,2)
do
    format_address $a
done
```

Comment: Nice. But the '-' must appear between the two sets:  

    066.035.005.123.00080-137.030.123.078.52172